# "Сдержанна" — это именное или отглагольное прилагательное?

Tags: прилагательные

**Сдержанна** во фразе "девушка была сдержанна" — это именное или отглагольное прилагательное? Почему?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, *отглагольное* - значение: она умеет (ей удаётся) *сдерживать* себя, это сдержа**нн**ая по характеру девушка. Даже искусственно (описанием фантастических ситуаций) не вывести это свойство из существительных "держатель" или "держава". Возможен и вариант краткого причастия (явно глагольной формы) - с одним "н": *атака была сдержа**н**а*.

Answer (score 0):

**Отглагольное.**

Отымённые прилагательные образуются от существительных и отвечают на вопрос «какой?» («какая?», «какое?», «какие?»). Отглагольные — от глаголов и отвечают на вопрос «каков?» («какова?», «каково?», «каковы?»): девушка была какова?

Answer (score 0):

Девушка была сдержанна.

Отглагольное (или отпричастное) прилагательное, схема образования: сдержать — сдержанный (прич.) — сдержанный (прилаг.).

Причастие при переходе обозначает не признак по действию, а качественный признак: сдержанная, замкнутая.

Парный вариант: Его эмоции были спокойны, сдержанны. Силы неприятеля были сдержаны и разгромлены.

Answer (score 0):

От глагола "сдержать", совершенный вид. Похоже на причастие, но нужно убедиться, что не перешло в прилагательное. Как это сделать? Попробовать заменить на конструкцию "которая + исходный глагол". Если получается это сделать без искажения смысла и смещения акцентов, значит причастие. Если нет, то прилагательное.

*девушка, которую сдержали*?

*девушка, которая сдержалась*?

Как видим, нарушается смысл, заменить нельзя, значит - отглагольное прилагательное.